# Is it usual for firmware to be only updatable in Windows?

Tags: laptop, firmware

http://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/36-Dell-firmware-problems-with-TSSTCorp-TS-L632D-DVD-drive.html

I want to update the firmware described in this blog post, but the author of that post, who has a dual-boot system and seems mostly to use Linux, says it is impossible to do in Linux.

Is that common? Why can't it be installed?

Comment: they stopped writing DOS-compatible flashers; and there is a download of Windows ; 7 at microsoft.com; however, OEMs are still using DOS tools nowadays, so ask the support..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, most hardware vendors only provide firmware update software for Windows or DOS.

In case of Dell, they have some tools that might be useful in some cases:

- [firmware-tools](http://linux.dell.com/wiki/index.php/Oss/Firmware_Tools) (this is also available in the Ubuntu repositories)
- BIOSdisk (a little bit of info + links to downloads [on this page](http://www.delltechcenter.com/page/Linux+Projects), scroll down a bit)

I'm not sure they support any laptops or desktops that they don't sell with Ubuntu pre-installed though...